# About $\mathbb{F}_7[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

can you help me with this?

Let $a(x)=3x^6+2x^2+x+5$ and $b(x)=6x^4+x^3+2x+4$, find the g.c.d between $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_7[x]$.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Do you know the 'classical' GCD algorithm?  Do you know how it looks in a polynomial context?

Comment: Wiyh what are you having troubly? Computing the gcd over $F_7$ is exactly the same as over any other field, really.

Comment: thanks ! it's really simple :)

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Univariate_polynomials_with_coefficients_in_a_field) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $b(x)$ has two linear factors. In fact, $b(x)=6(x^2+2)(x+5)(x+2)$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$. None of these factors is a factor of $a(x)$. This is easy to see. Hence $gcd(a(x),b(x))=1$.